# How can we make [loc] less ambiguous?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

The [loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loc) currently has a [tag wiki excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/loc/info) that reads:

> For questions concerning Lines of Code.

There are 306 questions tagged [loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loc), but it currently appears to mean at least 3 different things:

**pandas [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) indexer**

The vast majority (around 270 questions) seem to be in reference to the pandas indexer [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) which is used for label based indexing in pandas DataFrames and Series.

**Lines of Code**

The remaining 40ish questions do appear to be mostly about "lines of code" in various different contexts.

**Other**

There are also a few questions which appear to be unrelated to either of the above definitions. Like [How would I change a loc to a sub IDA Pro?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45971774/15497888) which uses [loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loc) to mean an address or location. Also [How to make the main axes transparent, while make the zoomed_inset_axes not transparent in matplolib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36147035/15497888) which uses [loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loc) to mean the `loc` parameter of `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator.zoomed_inset_axes`

---

Is the "Lines of Code" definition meaningful enough to keep as a tag? If yes, should it be renamed to be more clear what it represents? If no, should it be removed or should the guidance be updated to reflect the pandas [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) as the primary usage for [loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loc)?

Alternatively should a new tag like [pandas-loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas-loc) be created for pandas loc similar to the existing pandas method tags [pandas-groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas-groupby) and [pandas-melt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas-melt)?

Comment: LOC also stands for Library of Congress. That's a very ambiguous tag.

Comment: Are there a lot of programming questions about the Library of Congress?

Comment: How do you get knowledgeable in lines-of-code? Creating very long codes? Creating very short versions of code that word streamlined? Are you good after you created at least 100k lines of code?

Comment: Burnination seems to be the best option. Unless questions about lines of code are on-topic? I suppose we could allow questions that ask how to rewrite a function so that it uses X lines of code instead of Y...

Comment: A lot of them are not. But something like [Finding a repository LOC's added in a specific commit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5361317/15497888), for example, seems reasonable. Maybe it would be best to handle retagging pandas questions to pandas-loc first. Then once we only have the lines of code definition of loc we could look at burnination? @TylerH

Comment: @HenryEcker That's a good point, and yes I think that would be much better (though cleanup/re-tagging is always the first part of a tag request process where manual intervention is required, be it burnination, cleanup, or disambiguation).

Comment: @TylerH I can work on the pandas questions, it will take a bit because I'm sure there are some additional curation actions needed (closing/edits/ _etc_ ). Should there be a separate burninate request after the retagging happens to evaluate the remaining questions?

Comment: @HenryEcker No, it can remain all in this one since this is about LOC which was originally "lines of code" anyway

Comment: So it's fine to start retagging pursuant the answers below, then edit to swap disambiguation to burninate the remaining questions? @TylerH

Comment: Yes, this isn't a burnination request, so the burnination rules of featuring, waiting a specific time frame, waiting for mod intervention, etc. don't apply. The fact that Pandas `loc` indexer questions are using the wrong tag is an objective problem that should be fixed (and as 20k+ users we have the ability to create new tags and tag descriptions without needing assistance, in order to get started). I would recommend not retagging more than 5 to 10 questions per day, to avoid overwhelming the front page and anyone watching the pandas tag

Comment: @HenryEcker I would also recommend posting a CW answer here detailing what you are going to do and updating it every so often with your progress (and with some instructions of how others can help, e.g. "search for questions tagged [tag:pandas] and [tag:loc] and replace the [tag:loc] tag with [tag:pandas-loc] if the question is about that rather than lines of code".

Comment: LOC can also mean Law of Cosines `a^2 = b^2 + c^2 - 2(b)(c)(cos(theta))`, but I don't think the Law of Cosines would be appropriate for Stack Overflow

Comment: Suggested title: "Can we [loc]k down the meaning of this tag?"

Comment: @PatrickArtner: expertise with "lines of code" would likely be about how to count (e.g. how to ignore pure-comment lines, or account for coding styles that waste a line on a `{` between an if and the body).  Or using tools that do loc counts.  (Questions about the relevance of loc as a software metric probably aren't programming questions in the sense that SO defines it, though; possibly on-topic at softwareengineering.SE.)  Obviously the [lines-of-code] tag wouldn't apply to ever question that has lines of code in it.  It seems pretty niche, for sure.

Comment: Do any of the questions using LoC for "lines of code" benefit from the tag at all? Why should we stand in the way of what will likely become the more common usage in favor of... a relatively useless usage?

Comment: @KevinB I think I agree for the most part, but I'm not familiar enough with the non-pandas definition to make the decisions on that group of questions. [`[loc] -[pandas] -[dataframe] -[dask]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loc+-pandas+-dataframe+-dask) would give a reasonable starting point to see if the tag adds anything. I was unfamiliar with the "lines of code" definition prior to this so I don't know if it adds or detracts anything from this set of questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Summary of actions taken:

The misuse of [loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loc) in [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) / [dask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dask) / [dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dataframe) questions is now fixed.

The [loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loc) tag was removed from these questions in favour of the [pandas-loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas-loc) tag as these questions were not about "Lines of Code". Many questions were not about lines of code or pandas loc and had the tag removed entirely.

There is now basic tag info for [pandas-loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas-loc) and the [loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loc) excerpt to includes usage guidance which redirects to [pandas-loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas-loc) for pandas questions: "Do NOT use this tag for questions about the pandas loc indexer use [pandas-loc] instead."

---

### Status:

1. December 15, 2021: [pandas-loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas-loc) has been created
2. December 15, 2021: [loc/info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/loc/info) now contains updated usage guidance to redirect to [pandas-loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas-loc) for questions unrelated to lines of code
3. December 15, 2021: [pandas-loc/info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pandas-loc/info) now has basic usage guidance and tag wiki information.
4. December 31, 2021: All [`[loc] [pandas]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loc+pandas) questions have been retagged (239 questions were moved to [pandas-loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas-loc)). Thank you to all who helped in retagging.
5. January 4, 2022: A tag synonym was created from [loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loc) to [lines-of-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lines-of-code).
6. February 21, 2022: A tag synonym was created from [.loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.loc) to [pandas-loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas-loc)

Comment: “There is now basic tag info for pandas-loc and the loc excerpt to includes usage guidance which” no one will ever read or obey.

Comment: Case in point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70591607/python-pandas-to-frame-keyerror-after-converting-series-to-dataframe

Comment: It is true people don't tend to read the tag wikis. In all fairness, however, the loc excerpt guidance no longer exists due to the synonym redirecting to lines-of-code. Beyond this, we're still in a better situation because that's now a clearly incorrect tag, which another user should be able to handle.

Answer (score 35):

I would prefer to rename the [loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loc) tag to [lines-of-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lines-of-code), and then the majority of the original questions regarding pandas `loc` should be renamed as [pandas-loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas-loc).

And the rest of the questions regarding other kind of `loc`s should be retagged and removed from the posts.

Answer (score 15):

Can we rename `loc` to `lines-of-code` (with a possible alias)?

That said, I don't really see how lines of code by itself makes for a useful tag...

Comment: The tag is relevant to various static code analysis and code coverage topics.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis That's fair... though I can't think of a good generic "lines of code" question off the top of my head that wouldn't better suited to a tag for the specific software you're using...

Comment: `SLOC` (Source Lines of Code) should probably be an alias, although nobody's using it yet.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that many questions in the [loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loc) tag are in fact about Pandas, but lack the Pandas tag. The search `[loc] -[pandas]` can be used to search for these questions. Of course, not all of these are Pandas questions.

For those questions which are about the Pandas loc, I suggest tagging with [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas), and [pandas-loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas-loc).

Double check your work! Make sure you check that it is really a Pandas question. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58924771/get-value-at-some-memory-address-in-fortran), for example, used the [loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loc) tag, but is not about Pandas!

**EDIT**: Thanks to the hard work of many Pandas contributors, this is now done. Thanks all!

Answer (score -5):

This isn't ambiguous, the abbreviation "LoC" for lines of code is a very old and very established de facto standard term used by programmers since some 50 years back. It is used as a metric for code size and complexity. Those unaware of the term probably haven't worked with programming much/at all.

If some specialized niche technology is deciding to hijack this abbreviation for other purposes, it's unfortunate, but it isn't a problem created by SO but by those who named that technology while being unaware of basic programmer jargon.

Suggestion:

- Keep [loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loc) as it is, optionally make an alias [lines-of-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lines-of-code).
- Create a [pandas-loc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas-loc) and re-tag questions where appropriate.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the argument that an abbreviation which has [many different meanings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOC) is not ambiguous because one of the meanings is older. It seems to me that a newer definition being added to an older established term is what _causes_ ambiguity. In addition "Those unaware of the term probably haven't worked with programming much/at all." seems to imply that all programmers have similar education and work with similar technologies which is also an odd perspective given the breadth of technologies programmers interact with.

Comment: @HenryEcker It's not because it's older but because it is well-established. If I make a site about shaggy otters and call it SO, I don't come running here and demand that you stop calling the site SO.

Comment: I mean, they could demand whatever they want. fortunately there's no legal argument related to tag handling here.

Comment: Is it a term used by programmers or a term used by someone trying to find an arbitrary metric for programmer productivity?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Bugs per kLoC is a pretty common but rough metric to determine how bad a software development procedure is.